# How it is possible? Javascript variable not defined at Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, breakpoints

It is a strange behavior, when debug is on and the breakpoint is set the evaluated tool when I rollover the mouse the variable value appear, but when I call the same variable in console, the message is "not defined"

I already did this and aways works, but now is not working.

[image: image - situation]

In console...

encrypted (is ok)
"U2FsdGVkX18veAH/wTyK8DacXoNQd3/sfhfBUY/VpO2zxgCSOE/gTk+ewdqk0CJx0D0lNU4xtDAgyltvz3Bbpg=="

CryptoJS (is not ok)
VM2200:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined

Comment: Is your code transpiled before running, such as with babel and/or webpack, and are you using source maps?

Comment: The variable I want to see is CryptoJS and not encrypted. And yes, I using source maps.

Comment: Then it's unlikely to actually be called `CryptoJS`. Try disabling source maps or look at generated JS to determine actual variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Why, but I resolve creating a new variable reference to CryptoJS and works.

var cryptoJS = CryptoJS;
var encrypted = cryptoJS.AES.encrypt(cpfLimpo, "1234567890987654").toString();

If some one have a better response I apreciate.

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzmM2.png)